# Invariance of the Euler characteristic of a manifold with boundaries

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, topology, boundary-terms, gauss-bonnet

It is known that in a compact manifold of dimension $d=4$, the following integral is invariant under small deformations of the metric tensor
$$
\int_\mathcal M \sqrt{g}(R^2-4R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma})
$$
As a matter of fact, a theorem tells us that this computes the Euler characteristic of $\mathcal M$, $\chi[\mathcal M]$. As far as manifolds with boundaries are concerned, I found the following formula e.g. in https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00566
\begin{align}
\chi[\mathcal M]&=\frac{1}{32\pi^2}\int_\mathcal M \sqrt{g}(R^2-4R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}) \\
&-\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{\partial\mathcal M}\sqrt{h}(-R_{n\mu n\nu}k^{\mu\nu}+R_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu\nu}+R_{nn} k-\frac{1}{2}R k-\frac{1}{3}k^3+k \operatorname{Tr}k^2-\frac{2}{3}\operatorname{Tr}k^3)
\end{align}

I have computed the explicit variation of this quantity under a small deformation of the metric and it turns out to be dependent on the metric variation (and not on its derivatives) on $\partial\mathcal M$. Therefore, as long as I fix the metric on the boundary ($\delta g_{\mu\nu}= 0$), this quantity is indeed invariant. However, being a topological invariant, I would expect this number not to change even if the boundary is smoothly deformed, meaning that $\delta g_{\mu\nu}\ne 0$. Is there a formula for the Euler characteristic that captures this more general invariance?

Comment: I don't think this is that strange. In two dimensions the Gauss-Bonnet term reduces to the Einstein-Hilbert action on the surface, while the boundary term is the GHY term on the boundary of the surface. Thus, by construction, this does not depend on the *derivative* of the variation of the metric, but for this, we are obligated to use $\delta g |_{\partial \mathcal{M}}=0$. In a sense, I think that to show that the equations of motions of $\chi$ are indeed 0, you have to impose Dirichlet boundary conditions, because otherwise the problem is not well posed

Comment: Thank you for the comment @JeanbaptisteRoux
Do you think it is nevertheless possible to write a functional of the metric which is invariant under a transformation with generic boundary conditions (to be specific, in the problem I am studying, the boundary conditions would be conformal, meaning that the transformation reduces to a Weyl rescaling on the boundary)

Comment: You should probably add that you're talking about $d \leq 4$

Comment: I think this is, in fact, the other way around: one specifies boundary conditions and then searches for an action that is invariant by these boundary conditions, instead of searching for an action that is invariant under a generic boundary condition. I have found [Witten's article on conformal boundary conditions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11559), even though I don't think it addresses your question. There is also the concept of [Weiss variational](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.06897), which may be relevant to you.